# How do you update text in an event to be a three number RGB color (ex. 100,100,100) in pysimplegui?

Tags: python, colors

I want to make text that changes color depending on a pixel that was found earlier in the program but I cannot figure out how to turn an RGB color (ex. 100,100,100) into a color on pysimplegui. Is there any way to do that?

```
      elif event == "PDF Icon Color":
        print("Finding color")
        window["PDF"].update(text_color = (100,100,100))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PySimpleGUI looks like it takes colours as hex values, so you can convert the rgb value into hex first:

```py
def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb
rgb_to_hex((255, 255, 195)) #returns ffffc3
```

Then you can use your code:

```py
window["PDF"].update(text_color = rgb_to_hex((100,100,100)))
```

I'm not too sure if the # is required for hex values, if it is:

```py
window["PDF"].update(text_color = "#" + rgb_to_hex((100,100,100)))
```